# How to create a count up data frame

Tags: r

I’m trying to create a data frame in r that looks like this

```
X Y Z   
3 1 1    
3 1 2    
3 1 3    
3 2 1    
3 2 2    
3 2 3    
4 1 1    
4 1 2     
4 1 3     
4 2 1 
...
```

So column z counts up to 3 then when it reaches 3 column y increments by 1 and z counts up again until 3. Then x increments by 1 and the process starts again

Answer (score 5):

You could use `expand.grid` + `rev`

```
rev(expand.grid(z = 1:3, y = 1:2, x = 3:4))
   x y z
1  3 1 1
2  3 1 2
3  3 1 3
4  3 2 1
5  3 2 2
6  3 2 3
7  4 1 1
8  4 1 2
9  4 1 3
10 4 2 1
11 4 2 2
12 4 2 3
```

Comment: Your solution has 2 extra rows compared to OP.

Comment: @sindri_baldur OP had vertical dots to indicate that there were more rows

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use `tidyr::crossing()`.

In your case:

```r
crossing(X = 3:4,
         Y = 1:2,
         Z = 1:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.frame(X=rep(3:4,each=6,1),
           Y=rep(1:2,each=3,2),
           Z=rep(1:3,each=1,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R solution in addition to the `expand.grid` approach by [@Onyambu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60204573/12158757).

The feature of this code below is that, you only need to put everything into the list `lst`, and pass it to function `f`:

```
f <- function(lst) data.frame(mapply(function(p,n) rep(p,each=n),lst, prod(lengths(lst))/cumprod(lengths(lst))))

lst<- list(x = 3:4,y = 1:2,z = 1:3)
res <- f(lst)
```

such that

```
> res
   x y z
1  3 1 1
2  3 1 2
3  3 1 3
4  3 2 1
5  3 2 2
6  3 2 3
7  4 1 1
8  4 1 2
9  4 1 3
10 4 2 1
11 4 2 2
12 4 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` solution for completness:

```r
data.table::CJ(x = 3:4, y = 1:2, z = 1:3)

    x y z
 1: 3 1 1
 2: 3 1 2
 3: 3 1 3
 4: 3 2 1
 5: 3 2 2
 6: 3 2 3
 7: 4 1 1
 8: 4 1 2
 9: 4 1 3
10: 4 2 1
11: 4 2 2
12: 4 2 3
```